# Why useRef value dynamically updates when it is an integer but stores the previous value when it is a string?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I just learned useRef and am confused about how it actually works. For example,
#1

```
function Ref() {
  const rerenderCount = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    rerenderCount.current = rerenderCount.current + 1;
  });

  return <div>{rerenderCount.current}</div>;
}
```

Here, the useRef gives the same output as useState in the following code, #2

```
function State() {
  const [rerenderCount, setRerenderCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRerenderCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  });

  return <div>{rerenderCount}</div>;
}
```

But in this #3 code, the previousName.current value always displays the previous value. But it is set to name.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const previousName = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    previousName.current = name;
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <div>
        My name is {name} and it used to be {previousName.current}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Please, someone explain why the name is one step back where the integer updates on time. Also, what is the use of [name] in useEffect. Without or without it, I get the same result and rendercount.

Comment: `[name]` in useEffect is a dependency. Inside this array you declare a list of dependencies and when at least one of them changes the code inside useEffect is executed. the code is also run at the very first rendering. So you are changing `previousName.current` every time you type something in the input text. If you do not add any dependency `useEffect` will run every time the component gets re-rendered.

Comment: @Antonio Can please explain why the perviousName.current is always one letter behind name? like when I type 'abcd'.. name = 'abcd' but perviousName.current = 'abc'? It is inside useEffect so when name is updating why useRef is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you example `previousName` is one step behind because when you change the `name` state the component is re-render, useEffect is called and `previousName` is updated but this last change doesn't cause a new rendering (useRef is not like useState, the component is not re-render), so you see `name` updated correctly but `previousName` with the same value as before, even if its value has changed.
This is because the change of `previousName` occurs during the subsequent rendering caused by the changing on the state.
To see its change an additional rendering would require.
To avoid this behavior you could use an event handler and not rely on the useEffect hook.

```
const handleChange = (text: string) => {
    setName(text);
    previousName.current = text;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)} />
      <div>
        My name is {name} and it used to be {previousName.current}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I get it now, thank you.

Comment: If that's acceptable for you and you think it may be helpful for other people, please consider to make it accepted.